# Есть ли у MediaPlayer метод, который показывает текущую позицию и длительность воспроизведения?

Tags: mediaplayer, android, java

Чтобы видеть, сколько сек. осталось, как в WinAMP, полоска.

Есть ли у MediaPlayer какой-нибудь метод, который показывает текущую позицию и длительность воспроизведения? Короче, плеер хочу сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[первая ссылка в гугле](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). метод `getCurrentPosition`

Comment: @argamidon, хехе)), А Update слушатель есть же у него? Просто зачем создавать лишний поток, если он сам создает поток для себя, мне бы еще получить доступ к потоку, есть такое?

Comment: когда я писал свой, я создавал отдельный поток. И через handler обновлял. Это было давно, и слушателем я не интересовался.